# How do I fix a grid template issue with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I a trying to code the childhood toy 'Etch-a-Sketch' and I am using parents are childs to make a 16x16 grid system in the `.display`. The following code seems to not work, and I think it is an issue in the `grid-template-columns` and the `grid-template-rows` css code. Please help, thank you!

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Syne+Mono&display=swap');
    </style>

    <header class="header">
        <h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
    </header>

    <div class='display'></div>
    
    <button class='button'><span>Clear</span></button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: red;
}

.header {
    height:90px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 475px;
    top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
}

.display {
  height: 570px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16,1fr);
  
}

.button {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 535px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    font-family: 'Syne Mono', monospace;
  }
  
  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  
  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }


.square {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0];
const clear = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];





function grid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            console.log("yoyo");
            let square = document.createElement('div');
            square.className = 'square';
            display.appendChild(square);
        }
    }
};

grid();
```

Thank you for your time and effort reading and helping me with my situation, I hope it can be fixed! Have a great day!

[image: This is what is printing right now, the greyed part is supposed to have a 16x16 grid that is SHOWING in it. Sadly, the grid is not going throughout the WHOLE greyed area.]

This is what is printing right now, the greyed part is supposed to have a 16x16 grid that is SHOWING in it. Sadly, the grid is not going throughout the WHOLE greyed area.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you create 16 cells, but you want to fill a 16x16 grid - that means 256 cells. Look at your code in a simplified snippet:

```js
const display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0]
let k = 0

function grid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      let square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'square';
      square.textContent = ++k
      display.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
};

grid();
```

```css
.display {
  height: 570px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.square {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="display"></div>
```

If you change your JavaScript to the following:

```js
const display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0]
// let k = 0 // -> removed

function grid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      let square = document.createElement('div');
      square.className = 'square';
      // square.textContent = ++k // -> removed
      display.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
};

grid();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.display {
  height: 570px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.square {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="display"></div>
```

Then you have the whole grid.

### EDIT

With a little upgrade you can color the cells:

```js
function colorCell(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('red')
}

const display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0]

function grid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      let square = document.createElement('div');
      square.addEventListener('mouseover', colorCell)
      square.className = 'square';
      display.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
};

grid();
```

```css
.display {
  height: 570px;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.square {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square.red {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't fix my problem. I need the greyed out sections to be filled with the 1px solid border. The picture above will show what I have now, but I need that to fill throughout the whole grey part

Comment: @JakeS sorry, but then I don't get your problem exactly. Updated my answer (second snippet) by changing the colors of the `square`s & removing margin & padding. I feel what you mentioned as a problem with my answer was only due to colors.

Comment: The updated one answers my question, thank you so much!

Comment: How do I get rid of numbers though?

Comment: @JakeS you just remove them from the JS: no `let k` & no setting number in the `for` loop. Then the cells are empty.